# Clicking elements in a loop in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

This is what I am trying to do - I am trying to click on an element with a locator and on clicking that element, 2 more links are displayed. I want to individually click on those 2 links and then do an assertion.

However, the code clicks first element and then stops. This is my code -

```
self.expandHierarchy = function() {
var hrchy = element.all(by.css('.ng-binding.CanExpand'));
hrchy.each(function (elem) {
elem.click();
});
};
```

How can I do the same through protractor? All the elements have the same locator.

Answer (score 0):

That'll be a shot in the dark, but you may need to introduce a *short delay between the clicks*:

```
self.expandHierarchy = function() {
    var hrchy = element.all(by.css('.ng-binding.CanExpand'));
    hrchy.each(function (elem) {
        elem.click();
        browser.sleep(500);
    });
};
```

Or, instead, [wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for something that would indicate a link was clicked (depending on what happens on the page on the link click).